# Add random prefix to all cells in Excel

Tags: excel, random

I have a column with some text in each cell.
 I want to add 3 random prefixes to 1 column, for example "X","Y","Z" at the start of all cells.

[image: For example]

How to do that easy?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1, 3),"X","Y","Z")&" "&A1
```